# xgboost in R: Not getting train data correctly xgb.DMatrix

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm trying to get data in correct formatof dgCMatrix from dataframe.
However, I'm getting training data as NULL after applying xgb.DMatrix
Here's what I tried
My training data is

```
str(X_train)

            'data.frame':   5973 obs. of  6 variables:
             $ Gender              : Factor w/ 3 levels "","female","male": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
             $ OpenedDay           : Factor w/ 8 levels "","Friday","Monday",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
             $ MailOpenedHour      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
             $ OpenedAfterHrs      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
             $ OpenedAfterLoginDays: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
             $ Opened              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

After one hot encoding I get

```
    df_all <- X_train

    ohe_feats = c('Gender', 'OpenedDay')

    dummies <- dummyVars(~ Gender +  OpenedDay, data = df_all)
    df_all_ohe <- as.data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = df_all))
    df_all_combined <- cbind(df_all[,-c(which(colnames(df_all) %in% ohe_feats))],df_all_ohe)

    X_train1 <- df_all_combined

 str(X_train1)
'data.frame':   5973 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ MailOpenedHour      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedAfterHrs      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedAfterLoginDays: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Opened              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Gender.             : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Gender.female       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Gender.male         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Friday    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Monday    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Saturday  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Sunday    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Thursday  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Tuesday   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OpenedDay.Wednesday : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

My response variable is "Opened" so I seperate feature set from target

```
X_train <- X_train1[,-4]
X_target <- as.vector(X_train1[,4])
```

Now when I apply xgb.DMatrix, I get NULL result for xgtrain

```
 xgtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(X_train), label = X_target, missing = NA)
```

Note that more that 50% of the values are NA. Does this make it NULL.?

Any help would be great !

Comment: Could you dput some of your data? Please make sure what you post also creates this error.

Comment: It does'nt create an error..I'm getting the following:

 print(xgtrain)
 <pointer: 0x00000000097b07d0>
 attr(,"class")
 [1] "xgb.DMatrix"

Comment: This printout is as expected (at least in an older xgboost release that you seem to be using). DMatrix is accessed from R by a pointer to an external object in memory that is handled by xgboost library.